# What type of bulb is this?

Tags: identification, bulbs

Someone gave this bulb to my daughter. What is it?

[image]

Comment: What was the flower like? Is any of it still present on that thinner stem?

Comment: With the long linear leaves and the 'paper like' looking bulb, it could be a hyacinth bulb.   However, more information such as what Bamboo is asking would help.   Perhaps the friend who provided the bulb has some history on the bulb?